# Add a static image with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, image, webpack

I read many things on StackOverflow, but it still doesn't work in my case. Maybe could you help me to fix that ?

In my package :

```js
"file-loader": "^1.1.11",
"url-loader": "^1.1.1",
```

My webpack :

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: [
          'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
          'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000
    }
  },

};
```

My Code :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ImgExplore from './icon-explore.png';

export default class Landing extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>

        <img src={ImgExplore} className="img-fluid" />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I get this message

> ERROR in ./src/components/icon-explore.png Module build failed:
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
>
> > 1 | �PNG
> >         | ^   2 |    3 |    4 | IHDR��W�gAMA��
> >                         �a�IDATx�]    �Tյ=����U

Comment: you should use fileloader or urlloader for your images. Which version of webpack are you using ?